# how to get data from a txt file..split it into two variables and store and modify the this data to the array i used to store the data at the begining

Tags: java

Im creating a hotel reservation program.  I need to store the array which have the details into a txt file and load it afterwards when running the program again..

my data is not storing into the hotel array

```
public static void Write(String[] hotel){
     //storing information of the array into a text file
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.print("Do you want to write the data to a file(y/n) - ");
     String SaveTheFile=sc.nextLine();
     if(SaveTheFile.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){           
         try{
             FileWriter file  = new FileWriter("Hotel.txt");
             PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(file);
             for(int x =1;x<=10;x++){
             pr.println(+x+":"+hotel[x]+":");
             }
             pr.close();
             System.out.println("Write Successful");
             System.out.println("");
             Menu(hotel);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             System.err.println("Error!!!");
         }

     }else if(SaveTheFile.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
     //if the user entered 'n' going back to menu
         Menu(hotel);
     }else{
     //if the user entered any other, displaying an error message
         System.err.println("Please Enter 'y' or 'n' !!!");
         Write(hotel);
     }


 }

public static String[] Load(String[] hotel){
    String line = null;
    String numSt,name;
    int num;

    System.out.println("");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Hotel.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] token = line.split(":");
                            numSt = token[0];
                            name = token[1];                            
                            num = Integer.parseInt(numSt);                                
                            hotel[num]=name;


        }
        br.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found");                                         
    }
            catch (NullPointerException f) {
        System.out.println("Null pointer here...");
                     }
            return hotel;

    }
```

I found out the answer......

```
        String line = "";
        int counter = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            numSt = line.split(":")[0];
                            name = line.split(":")[1];                          
                            counter = Integer.parseInt(numSt);                                
                            hotel[counter]=name;
                            counter++;
```

Thank u for spending your valuable time for helping me to sort this out :)

Comment: you have enter the full file path in the reader...

Comment: Use Exception#printStackTrace to provide you more information about where the error is occurring

Comment: It shows this...

    java.lang.NullPointerException 
 at HotelRooms.Load(HotelRooms.java:272)
 at HotelRooms.Menu(HotelRooms.java:67)
 at HotelRooms.main(HotelRooms.java:24)

Comment: hey i found out the solution ... :) :)

Comment: 'String line = "";'
   int counter = 0;

   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                numSt = line.split(":")[0];
                                name = line.split(":")[1];                          
                                counter = Integer.parseInt(numSt);                                
                                hotel[counter]=name;
                                counter++;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String line = null;
```

You never give this variable an actual value other than null so it will be null when you first use it. If this is not the error please provide the log.

Comment: Thank you...it was the reason...but the thing i was trying to do is to get the information which was stored in the text  which was like 

"1:Mark
2:john"

and split the numbers and names into two different variables and add those data to my array.